# Prevent WPF Window From Minimizing (Winkey + D, mostly)

Tags: wpf, minimize

I have a window which is supposed to act like a Windows Vista(+) gadget; its supposed to stay on the desktop, not to appear on taskbar and the alt+tab menu, but most importantly, not to get minimized.

Here is its header:

As its style is set to None, it has no control buttons (minimize, close, etc...) but it still can be minimized using the "Show Desktop" feature and the Winkey+D combination.

How can I prevent that from happening?

Thanks!

Comment: When I hit Winkey+D ALL my windows minimize including any gadget windows. I think that this is the exact intention of the keyboard shortcut, and trying to circumvent it will most likely not please your users.

Comment: Well, I just added some gadgets (Windows 7) and Winkey+D did not minimize them, as I would expect from gadgets.

Moreover, gadgets do not appear on Alt+Tab menu and on the Taskbar, which means that minimizing them == losing them.

Answer (score 2):

"Show Desktop" does more than just minimize windows - after minimizing all the windows it can, it then brings the desktop window to the top of the z-order. [Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/05/27/143042.aspx) has a good explanation of this.

You could mark your window as "always on top" but then it would appear on top of every window. I can't think of any other way of preventing Show Desktop from hiding your window. A quick experiment with Windows Sidebar shows that it is also minimized on Show Desktop unless you set the "Sidebar is always on top of other windows".