# WPF - Make a window re-open when minimized

Tags: c#, wpf, minimize, maximize

I've been trying to make a program, that makes an ellipse move on the screen (by the arrow keys), when I am still able to click the window that is open behind it (for example - Google Chrome) and the ellipse will still be visible and move-able.

I've been trying a lot of things (including `TopMost`) and nothing worked.

Now, my idea is to make a transparent window, that is un-clickable and will re-open (will be maximized) every time it gets minimized.

Can someone please help me? I have no code that can help, the names of the objects involved don't matter.

Answer (score 1):

I think your questions are already answered elsewhere:

1. [Click-through control in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988281/how-can-i-click-through-a-control-in-wpf) (use `<TextBlock IsHitTestVisible="False" .../>`)
2. Preveting the window from minimizing:

   a. [Cancel minimizing event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022921/how-to-cancel-the-wpf-form-minimize-event) (intercept the minimize event and cancel it)

   b. [Preventing from minimizing on "Show Desktop" (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388453/prevent-wpf-window-from-minimizing-winkey-d-mostly) (mark the window always-on-top)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11956279)

Comment: @kerem – OK, corrected. (Although in this case links are only internal ones and their Q/A's are relatively solid, i.e. they do not look to be deleted soon.)

Comment: None of these work, because I want the window to be click-through (like option 1), but when I try to click it makes the computer to focus on the window behind, and I want to prevent that

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question right, you want to click through the ellipse.

You could for example just use two grids with different ZIndex and just Register when 1 gets clicked. Eg:

```
<Grid>
     <Grid Background="Transparent" Panel.ZIndex="1">

     </Grid>    
     <Grid Panel.ZIndex="0">
          <Ellipse Background="Blue" Height="100" Width="200"/>
     </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You didn't understand, I want to prevent the window from minimizing, but also make the window behind it clickable.